# Send boolean intent from onBackPressed() to onStart()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send an intent from the `Map` activity to the `MainActivity` when I press the back button in the `Map` activity. The intent should be received in the `onStart()` of the `MainActivity` but I am just getting  for `extras` `NULL` there. The variable `serviceStatus` in the Map activity is set when the user clicks the button in the actionbar. I want to set the status of the service in the actionbar of the MainActivity.

I have tried to send the intent from the `finish()` in the Map activity but I am getting null for extras too.

How can I fix it?

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends ActionBarActivity{
 boolean serviceStatus;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();      
        Intent serviceStatusIntent = new Intent(Map.this, MainActivity.class);
         // I have debugged it and serviceStatus is false here also the intent exists.
        serviceStatusIntent.putExtra("ServiceStatusMapExtras", serviceStatus);
        startActivity(serviceStatusIntent);
    }
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
boolean serviceStatus = true;
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();                
        Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();
        //I am receiving null here.     
        if(extras != null){
            serviceStatus = extras.getBoolean("ServiceStatusMapExtras");

        }
```

Comment: doing it in onCreate does that help ?

Comment: also finish() return when you have started an activity for result, but i see you are starting your activity when you press your back button. is there any design constraint because of which you want the data back when the back button is pressed ?

Comment: @hars: I dont have specific desig constrains but I just want to sent the boolean value when I press the back button. I have tried it in `onCreate()` but the methodf is not being called again when it is once  created and a new activity is being started from it.

Comment: yes so you mean you already have the MainActivity in the back stack.

Comment: Are you starting your MapActivity from your MainActivity first ?

Comment: @hars: I am starting my MainActivity from another class. So when the user clickes a button the mainActivity,  alarmManager and IntentService are being triggered to retrieve data from the server when the data IS attained The Map activity is being started from an intentService class `GETLLRD`.

Comment: When I click the back button the alarmManager is being stopped.

Comment: can I use sharedpreferences to solve the probelm?

Comment: lets continue here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88626/discussion-between-mr-asker-and-hars

Answer (score 1):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();`

Fix `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
      boolean serviceStatus = true;
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();                
            serviceStatus =  getIntent().getBooleanExtra("ServiceStatusMapExtras", false);

       }
}
```